# Get a random link from my links table once every 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of links in my database and I am trying to make a page on my app called 'link of the day'.

What I want to do is get a random link from my links table once every 24 hours (for testing purposes once every 30 seconds or so) and then make sure that each value that is picked every 24 hours does not get selected again.

links_controller.rb:

```
  def quote_of_the_day
    @links = Link.all
  end
```

quote_of_the_day.html.erb:

What I am trying to say here is every 30 seconds, give me a random link from my links_array.

```
<% @links_array = @links.to_a %>
<% @time = Time.now %>
<% @time_plus_30 = @time + 30 %>

<% when @time_plus_30 %>
    <%= @links_array.try(:sample) %>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction on what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Your "equal" operator is wrong. You need to use "=" instead of comparison operator "==".

Comment: Don't put that code in your view. Do it in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) Unless you use something like [react.rb](http://reactrb.org) the links won't dynamically update.  But you said 24 hours, so I assume you just expect that if a user visits your site the next day they will see a different link.  That's fine.

2) For testing you will have to just refresh the page and it should look the same for the first 30 seconds, and then finally after 30 seconds if you refresh again it will change.

3) You want to move all the logic to controller and the model.  You will need to use the rails cache to store the link you have randomly chosen, and then expire the cache value in "timeout" time (1 day, 30 seconds, whatever).  Luckily this is easy in rails.

4) If you really want to be sure that a link is never displayed again (at least until all other links have been displayed) you will have to add a counter to the model

So specifically (working backwards)

Add an attribute `display_count` to the `Link` model.  Make sure its an integer value that is initialized to zero (not nil.)

Add a method `get_new_url` to the model.  It looks like this

```
 def self.get_new_url
   # get the minimum value of display_count from the db
   min_count = minimum(:display_count) 
   # build a query to get all the links with same count
   min_links = where(display_count: min_count) 
   # pick a random offset by counting the links with the same count
   random_link_offset = rand(0..min_links.count-1) 
   # select the link that is at that offset
   link = min_links.limit(1).offset(random_link_offset).first
   # don't forget to update its count and save it
   link.display_count += 1
   link.save
   link
 end
```

Finally in your controller you will do this

```
  def get_link
    Rails.cache.fetch("current_random_link", expires_in: 24.hours) do
      Link.get_new_url # will only be called every 24 hours when the cache expires
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just a note - what a great opportunity to learn to use all the rails and ruby testing goodness. You can build very nice test cases for the above method in the model, and if you want for the controller (although the model is doing all the hard work so I would focus on testing that)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Mitch. 

Currently I have the cache set to expire after `10.seconds`  in the controller and I set ` @link = Link.get_new_url`. 

Then I called @link in my view to see if I would get the object back, but I have been having difficulty retrieving the object. 

I ran a migration to include `display_count` in my link table and set the default to 0. 

I then updated all of my current links with `Link.update_all "display_count = 0"`. 

The links are still not coming through. Do you see an error in what I have done?

Comment: run a `rails console`, then you can just play in there (i.e. do a Link.get_new_url) and see what is going on.

Comment: while in the console you can basically simulate whate get_new_url does... i.e. type each line of the method in the console and see where things are going wrong, going wrong, going wrong, going wrong

Comment: Console shows it is working brilliantly. Not sure why it's not coming across in my view. Probably an oversight by me at the moment. Thanks so much!

Comment: Any idea why @link would be coming across as nil? It doesn't make sense since every time I run `@link = Link.get_new_url` in my console it returns a link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99994/discussion-between-mitch-vanduyn-and-jbur43).